# How to integrate and visualize 1d kde with scipy?

Tags: python, math, scipy

I have a 1d array, and I have used scipy.stats.gaussian_kde to get the pdf. Now I want to compute the integral of each particular data point and my code is as below. Does this make sense? if not, what is the correct solution? Btw,how can I visualize the pdf and the integral function? Thanku

```
X=np.array([0.21,0.21,0.21,0.28,0.30,0.30,0.24,0.22,0.19,0.20,0.18,0.23,0.20,0.12,0.14,0.13,0.18,0.15,0.13,0.11,0.12,0.11,0.10,0.13,0.03,0.07,0.17,0.16])
kde=scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(X, bw_method=None, weights=None)
for x in X:
    print(kde.integrate_box_1d(-np.inf, x))
```

Answer (score 0):

To plot the `kde`, you need to create a dense array of x-values. The integral at the given points can be plotted via a scatter plot.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import  numpy as np
import scipy, scipy.stats

X = np.array([0.21,0.21,0.21,0.28,0.30,0.30,0.24,0.22,0.19,0.20,0.18,0.23,0.20,0.12,0.14,0.13,0.18,0.15,0.13,0.11,0.12,0.11,0.10,0.13,0.03,0.07,0.17,0.16])
kde = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(X, bw_method=None, weights=None)
xmin = X.min()
xmax = X.max()
# create an array of x values for plotting
xs = np.linspace(xmin - (xmax - xmin) * 0.2, xmax + (xmax - xmin) * 0.2, 500)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(12, 10), sharex=True)
ax1.plot(xs, kde(xs), color='dodgerblue')
ax1.set_ylim(ymin=0)
ax1.set_title('kde')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelbottom=True)
for x in X:
     ax2.scatter(x, kde.integrate_box_1d(-np.inf, x), color='crimson')
ax2.set_ylim(ymin=0)
ax2.set_title('integral of kde at given X values')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: showing kde and its integral]